# Tastypie - Dehydrate not called on POST?

Tags: python, django

I need to access dehydrate to modify some data before it goes to validation (I can't modify the data in validation because I need access the the request object). However, my debugging statements indicate that POST requests aren't even reaching my dehydrate method (GET requests do reach it). Here is my dehydrate method, inside of a PostResource:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    print 'in dehydrate'
    bundle.data['location_model'] = self.get_via_uri(bundle.data['location'], bundle.request)
    return bundle
```

How can I call dehydrate in a post method?

Answer (score 1):

Set `always_return_data = True` in your resource `Meta`.